# Removing a Password From a LUKS+EXT4 encrypted HDD

Tags: linux, hard-drive, encryption

Many years ago I formatted my Toshiba External Hard with **Ext4** file system (**So that it can only open in Linux**). It has been working perfectly well ever since. Even right now, it works perfectly well on my Ubuntu 16.01
But I now want to remove the password and change the file system to **FAT32** so that I can start **accessing it in Windows** platforms (Windows 10).

**How can I do that without having to format and lose my data. I have quite a lot of data and I don't wanna lose it or transfer it first.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two separate problems here:

1. Being able to unlock the LUKS encryption layer on Windows.

   A few years ago, FreeOTFE used to do this quite well. Later it was developed under the [LibreCrypt](https://t-d-k.github.io/LibreCrypt/) name, although even that seems to have been abandoned.

   If you still have Linux, it is possible to decrypt the entire disk in-place:

   ```
   cryptsetup-reencrypt /dev/sdb1 --decrypt
   ```
2. Being able to access the ext4 filesystem on Windows.

   For this you can use the [Ext2fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/files/Ext2fsd/) driver.

If you decide to convert to a native Windows filesystem instead, you'll have to back up everything and reformat the disk. I haven't heard of any tool that could convert from ext4 to FAT or NTFS.

Also, I **strongly** recommend NTFS (or at least exFAT) over FAT32.

Comment: Can I use that Ext2fsd on Windows with the encryption still intact?
I know the phrase (password)

Comment: If you can get LibreCrypt/FreeOTFE working, yes.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to convert `ext4` file-system to `FAT32`. You need to format your HDD.

Comment: That would mean losing all my data?

Comment: Yes. You need backup your data first.